# How complex CSS selectors work

Tags: css, css-selectors

Guys I am working on complex CSS selectors from some third party source. I am not able to user stand few things.

How nested CSS works. I am seeing lots of nested CSS like.

```
.firstclass
{
   .someotherclass { }
}
```

sometimes.

```
.firstclass.secondclass
{
   .thirdclass{}
   .fourthclass{}

}
```

Also I tried sample code below my expectation is background color for second text box will become 'BLACK' but it is not happening.

```
<html>

   <head>

   <style type="text/css">

   .style-color
   {
       background-color:#000000;
   }

   #id2_.style-color h1
   {   
       background-color:#F0E68C;
       .apply
       {
           background-color:#000000;
       }


   }
   </style>
   </head>

   <body> 

   <div id="id1" class="style-color"> <h1> <input type="text" class="apply"> </h1> </div> 
   <div id="id2_" class="style-color"> <h1> <input type="text" class="apply"> </h1></div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is not "native" CSS, but something like LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a valid CSS. If you are seeing that code its mostly dynamic CSS. SASS and LESS are examples of dynamic CSS. They add programming capabilities to CSS. You can use SCOUT compiler for SASS. Google it.

Comment: Yes it is using SAAS just referred their web site how to get started with SAAS for normal demo/hello world program.

Comment: Abhijit any good place to get started with this. Installation itself is looking complex.

Comment: http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/ This link will guide you to through the installation process.

Comment: I installed but it does not work out of the box. I am getting some ruby error while compiling the file.                           NoMethodError on line 264 of C: source
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2096:in `send'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:262:in `method_missing' C:\Program Files (x86)\Scout\config\Gemfile:21:in `parse_string' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval' C:/Program Files (x86)/Scout/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string' C:/Program Files

Answer (score 0):

I found what ever third party source code I was using is using SAAS internally. Hence I got confused.

Now I am clear on this front so I will try to understand SAAS and the way it works.